# backpO2 function in script below not working any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Tags: equation-solving

```
K3[T_] := E^(10.929155015247563` - 21.002500855040577` T);

K4[T_] := E^(14.595439006954816` - 36.90755551742593` T);

Temps = Table[i, {i, 1001, 1800, 100}];

deltaz = Table[i, {i, 10^-2, 2*10^-1, 10^-3}];

Delta[T_?NumberQ, pO2input_?NumberQ] := 
 d /. NSolve[{(d^0.5*(0.2 - 2*d - 1)*
         pO2input^0.25)/((0.2 - 2*d)*(3 - d)^0.5) == 
              ((3 - d)^0.5*(2*d - 0.2 - 1)*
          K4[1000/T])/(d^0.5*(0.2 - 2*d)*
                     pO2input^0.25) - K3[1000/T]^0.5, d > 0}, {d},Reals][[1]]

backpO2[T_, d_] := 
  pO2_ /. FindInstance[Delta[T, pO2_] == d, pO2_][[1]][[1]];
```

pO2pm = Table[ Table[backpO2[Temps[[i]], deltaz[[j]]], {i, Length[Temps]}], {j, Length[deltaz]}]; 
In addition I want to create a table of pO2 values using the output of the backpO2 function as described in this line but this is also not working.

Comment: It's a good start, you posted the code - now why isn't it working, how do you expect it to work?  What values of `T` and `d` do you expect to get reasonable results for?

Comment: But right away I can see that you should remove the underscores from the `pO2` on the last line (I think)

Comment: I have used the exact script to solve the backpO2 function with underscores so that's why they are there. I'm not sure why backpO2 is not working; the values of T and d that I'm interested in are within the definitions for Temps and deltaz in the script.

Comment: pO2pm = Table[
   Table[backpO2[Temps[[i]], deltaz[[j]]], {i, Length[Temps]}], {j, 
    Length[deltaz]}];  In addition I want to create a table of pO2 values using the output of the backpO2 function as described in this line but this is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version of `backpO2` that uses a numerical solver (`FindRoot`) instead of `FindInstance`:

```
Clear[delta, backpO2]

delta[T_?NumericQ, pO2input_?NumericQ] := 
 d /. First@NSolve[{(d^0.5 (0.2 - 2 d - 1) pO2input^0.25) / ((0.2 - 2 d) (3 - d)^0.5) == 
           ((3 - d)^0.5 (2 d - 0.2 - 1) K4[1000/T]) / (d^0.5 (0.2 - 2 d) pO2input^0.25) - 
           K3[1000/T]^0.5, d > 0}, d]

backpO2[T_, d_] := pO2 /. FindRoot[delta[T, pO2] == d, {pO2, 1*^-6}]

Plot[backpO2[t, 0.015], {t, 1100, 1800}, PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 1]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great resource!